# How to enable a website on apache2 virtual server running Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, ubuntu-12.04, website

I managed to run one website on my apache2 virtual server using port 80.
now I want to have another site running on the same server, but I can't manage it.

Either I corrupt my old page or my folder of the new page is displayed. For the new page I use port 81.

Here are my steps :

copied all items to `/data/website2` and made a link to `/var/www/website2`

I put my configuration to /etc/apache2/sites-available/website2

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
        ServerAdmin me@localhost.de
        DocumentRoot /var/www/website2

        <Directory /var/www/website2>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

now I enable this page using : `a2ensite website2`
and then reload apache2     : `sudo service apache2 reload`

when I now enter the website from local using my ip address :

```
192.168.xxx.xx/website2  my www folder is displayed. Did I link something incorrect maybe?
```

Do I have to configurate my `/etc/apache2/hosts` config?

in my hosts file I have this :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Of course I enabled my port 81 in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

Thank you in Advance. If any Information is missing, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your are running local server :

You can run both website on port 80 and use ServerName directive in your virtualhost (but this involve to edit your host file to fit the vhost directive)

VirtualHost for your first website :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAdmin me@localhost.de
        DocumentRoot /var/www/website

        <Directory /var/www/website>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

VirtualHost for your second website :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example2.com
        ServerAdmin me@localhost.de
        DocumentRoot /var/www/website2

        <Directory /var/www/website2>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You need to edit your host file with  www.example.com and www.example2.com entries.

Comment: Maybe you could try Alias directive in you vhost too : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12879429)

Comment: Am I allowed to use localhost as ServerName for both? and just have different directories for the sites? Or does this cause problems?

Comment: This is possible but I prefer not to use localhost.
You can have only one vhost (For your first website) and add an Alias directive (Alias /website2 /path/to/site) that point to your second website directory wich have to be inside your DocumentRoot